# HTML: need help reducing white spaces between image table rows

Tags: html

I managed to reduce the white space between images on the same row of a table for blogger.com, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to reduce the white space between the rows of images.  Below is the HTML I currently have.  Any suggestions?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" style="width: 900px;"> <tbody>
<tr><td valign="top" width="209">

<img src="URL" height="130" style="background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; display: inline; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px width="200"/>

...

<img src="URL" height="130" style="background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; display: inline; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px width="200"/>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were missing a `"` before `width="200"`
You did not have a closing `</td>`
You did not have a closing `</tr>`
You had `cellspacing="5"` -- changed to `cellspacing="0"`

Here is your code with the corrections

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 900px;"> <tbody>
<tr><td valign="top" width="209">

<img src="URL" height="130" style="background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; display: inline; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px" width="200" />

<img src="URL" height="130" style="background-image: none; border-bottom: 0px; border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; display: inline; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px" width="200"/></td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Here is the code working on jsFiddle

[Demo Of Above Code](http://jsfiddle.net/NM64L/)

Comment: Edited answer as I originally just posted the URL to jsfiddle, but not the specific link [http://jsfiddle.net/NM64L/](http://jsfiddle.net/NM64L/)

Comment: You are welcome. If this solution worked for you, please click the greyed out checkmark to the left.  Also, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You've zeroed the borders and padding on the images, but there may be margins.  Try zeroing margin-top, margin-bottom, etc.

Are the images all in one table cell or in separate table cells?  cellspacing="5" will add spacing between cells, and he table cells may add padding.

Try loading your page in your browser's inspector.  I'm not sure off hand about IE, but Firefox and Chrome both have ways to see all of the margins, padding, etc. on selected nodes.

Comment: Tried your suggestion of zeroing margin-top and margin-bottom, and it had no effect.  I also adjusted cellspacing to 0 ad Sanuel suggested.